# Append newline variables together shell script

Tags: bash, shell, paste

In a shell script, I have two variables which are created as:

```
newvar1=`echo "$var1"`
newvar2=`echo "$var2"`
```

Eg
newvar1:

```
A|1
B|2
```

newvar2:

```
K/L/M
X/Y/Z
```

Need to get output like

```
A|1:K/L/M
B|2:X/Y/Z
```

Comment: Why do you need `echo`? Will this be shorter: `newvar1="$var1"` ?
`

Answer (score 5):

Use `paste` to print the lines side by side. They're delimited by tabs by default; we can change that to colons with `-d ':'`.

```
paste -d ':' <( echo $'A|1\nB|2' ) <( echo $'K/L/M\nX/Y/Z' )
```

Output:

```
A|1:K/L/M
B|2:X/Y/Z
```

If you use variables make sure to quote them to preserve the newlines:

```
paste -d ':' <( echo "$newvar1" ) <( echo "$newvar2" )
```